# lxml - Default name spaces

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to parse an xml file using `lxml`.

```
my_tree = etree.parse(file)
my_root = my_tree.getroot()

for child in my_root:
    print(child.tag)

# {some default namespace}Prop
# {some default namespace}Prop
# {some default namespace}Stuff
# ...
```

Ideally, I just want to get all the elements I want with something like

```
my_root.findall('Prop', my_root.nsmap)
```

but this is returning an empty list. I noticed that the `my_root.nsmap` dictionary had a None item with the default namespace.

```
nsmap = {None: 'default namespace', ...}
```

I found a quick workaround by copying the nsmap and adding a 'default' item with the same value as the None item, and then I do

```
my_root.findall('default:Prop', new_map)
```

This feels very hackish. Why is None even in the namespace map? Is there some straightforward method in lxml the automatically uses the default namespace?

Edit: The xml I am looking at is along the lines of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ScenarioProps xmlns="http://filler.com/default.xsd" xmlns:ns2="http://filler.com/ns.xsd" id="Test">
    <Prop id="Wi-Fi">
        <ns2:Position x="0.0" y="0.0" z="0.0"/>
        <ns2:Orientation roll="0.0" pitch="0.0" yaw="0.0"/>
    </Prop>
</ScenarioProps>
```

Comment: Please show us the XML source (preferably trimmed down as much as possible, just enough to reproduce the issue).

Comment: @mzjn edited. Hopefully that is enough to be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hackish or not, you have to specify a prefix. **XPath 1.0**, which is what lxml supports, does not have a concept of default namespace (it works differently in **XPath 2.0**, but that does not apply here).

The other option is to not bother with prefixes at all. Use the fully qualified element name in "Clark notation" instead:

```
 my_root.findall('{http://filler.com/default.xsd}Prop').
```

See also http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#how-can-i-specify-a-default-namespace-for-xpath-expressions.

### Update August 2019

The behaviour has changed in later versions of lxml. With lxml 4.4.1, both `None` and the empty string can be used:

```
from lxml import etree
 
my_tree = etree.parse("props.xml")
my_root = my_tree.getroot()
 
NS = 'http://filler.com/default.xsd'
 
NSMAP1 = {None: NS}
NSMAP2 = {'': NS}
NSMAP3 = {'default': NS}
 
print(my_root.findall('Prop', NSMAP1))
print(my_root.findall('Prop', NSMAP2))
print(my_root.findall('default:Prop', NSMAP3))
```

Output:

```
[<Element {http://filler.com/default.xsd}Prop at 0x31f1260>]
[<Element {http://filler.com/default.xsd}Prop at 0x31f1288>]
[<Element {http://filler.com/default.xsd}Prop at 0x31f1260>]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at namespaces at http://lxml.de/tutorial.html I was under the impression, the None key was for the default namespace. Thanks for clearing things up

Answer (score 2):

I just use a helper class. `context` is the document, `my` is the namespace, and `key` is the tag name.

```
found = self.context.find('.//{%s}%s' % (self.my, key))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can "automatically" redefine your default namespace with something like:

```
{k if k is not None else 'default':v for k,v in my_root.nsmap.items()}
```

which gets a namespace dictionary with the key None replaced by "default" and leaves all other keys untouched:

```
{'default': 'http://filler.com/default.xsd', 'ns2': 'http://filler.com/ns.xsd'}
```

your example would look as follows:

```
from lxml import etree
import StringIO
f = StringIO.StringIO('''
<ScenarioProps xmlns="http://filler.com/default.xsd" xmlns:ns2="http://filler.com/ns.xsd" id="Test">
    <Prop id="Wi-Fi">
        <ns2:Position x="0.0" y="0.0" z="0.0"/>
        <ns2:Orientation roll="0.0" pitch="0.0" yaw="0.0"/>
    </Prop>
</ScenarioProps>
''')
parser = etree.XMLParser()
my_tree = etree.parse(f, parser)
my_root = my_tree.getroot()
my_tree.getroot().nsmap
nsmap = {k if k is not None else 'default':v for k,v in my_root.nsmap.items()}
my_root.findall('default:Prop', nsmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Helpful answers above! In order to use xpath without explicitly defining the namespace for default, I would suggest:

1. setting namespace to `''` with

```
nsmap={k if k is not None else '':v for k,v in root.nsmap.items()}
```

2. then parsing the xml document

```
root.findall('Prop', nsmap)
```